# knockoutjs anchor click causing page scroll to top if response is array

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, knockout.js

I'm seeing some very strange behavior. I have two anchor tags and both have data-bound click events, both make ajax requests. In one case, if the response is an array the click will cause the page to scroll to the top. In the other case, if response is NOT an array the click will not cause the page to scroll at all.

Here are my 2 cases

```
<a data-bind="click: click1">click 1</a>  # scrolls to top
<a data-bind="click: click2">click 2</a>  # does not scroll

# javascript
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this; 

  self.click1 = function(data, event) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/movies",     // returns array of movies, scrolls to top
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        movie_list = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        self.movies(movie_list);
      }
  }

  self.click2 = function(data, event) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/movies/1",   // returns just one movie, does not scroll
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        movie_details = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        self.movies(movie_details);
      }
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Any idea how to stop the first case from causing the page to scroll to the top?

Comment: Is there already a list of movies rendered at the time when this unwanted scrolling occurs? Doing self.movies(movie_list) will blow away the contents of the ObservableArray and rebuild it from movie_list - is that what you intend? Rather than doing updates / inserts, which you might consider the mapping plugin for?

Comment: @TomHall the behavior is the same whether or not a list of rendered movies exists. And yes, replacing the whole movie_list is what I want (rather than adding to the list).

Comment: It sounds from this: https://gist.github.com/2988758 as if the same issue occurs when simply pushing new items onto the array. I can only presume it comes down to how the DOM gets rebuilt by Knockout as the bindings are updated. Is it feasible for now at least for you to store the current page offset and restore it after updating your view model?